# Correct word choice

Tags: word-choice

For example, in a factory workers get the extra money per piece of product. Is the sentence below correct to describe this situation?

> the workers work with a premium paid per number of products completed, beside the salary on a weekly basis.

1)Can my sentences be understood by a native speaker and is it grammatically correct?

2)What would a native speaker say for this situation?

Comment: Your sentence would be understood, but it could be better arranged. **As well as** (or **on top of**) **their weekly salary, employees receive a premium per product completed**. Or we might say, **Piecework pay is added to the workers' weekly salary.**

Comment: Is there any grammatical mistake in my sentence?

Comment: _per_ means _for each_. We would say, "for each product" or "per product": not "each number of products." "Beside" often means "next to" or "at the side of". "Besides" (with an **s**) means "as well" or "in addition" and avoids possible ambiguity. We know workers work.

Comment: Not *per number of products*, but *per product*. They do not receive extra pay for each different number of products